# Multiple calls to ASP.NET WEB API with mobile clients Vs. One single call

Tags: android, mobile, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, appcelerator

I'm going to implement a Web API to be consumed by mobile devices (android, iOS) and web applications. From what I understand about Web API, it should be client-agnostic, so no matter which client consumes it: a mobile app, a web application, a console application, etc.

My concern comes when a mobile developer suggested me to design all the API methods according the mobile app views. For example, in one view I need to display information about a user and its products, I think I need to create 2 methods:

- /users/231
- /users/231/products/1453

But according the mobile developer I need to create **only one method** that returns all the view data in only one call:

- views/initialviews/params

His main argument is that we need to reduce calls to server. But the disadvantage I see, is that if at some point the screens/views change, we'll need to change the API, also other clients could implement different views structures.

Is it a good practice to provide API methods per view , only one call that returns all the data required in that view?
or
is it better to handle atomic/single responsability methods in API to be consumed by clients no matter how many calls clients do to the server?

Please, guide me a little about this, and tell me if the multiple calls affect performance or have disadvantages.
I think no matter how many calls client do, if the response from server is milliseconds. So client works with a composition of calls.

Any article or more references is welcomed too.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: My question is more oriented to if multiple calls are an antipattern in mobile applications? For example, to do 4 calls to retrieve data from view to view, because API is supposed to return atomic/specific responses.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could implement Batch-Requests? Facebook also uses [this approach](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests).

- [Web Api Batching](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20API%20Request%20Batching)
- [How to avoid 26 Requests in your API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/855284/How-to-Avoid-API-Requests-On-Your-Page)
- [Introducing batch support in Web API and Web API OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx)